# Write getter for Seconds of Fast Days

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, time

I have a function called getDayTimeParameter(), which gets the day parameter from 0 to 1. I also have two functions which are getters of hour and minute. I need to show time as hh:mm:ss. But the problem is I have no idea how to write getter for seconds. Thanks in advance!

```
    public float getDayTimeParameter()
    {
        return System.DateTime.Now.Minute / 60f + System.DateTime.Now.Second / 3600f + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond / 3600000f;
    }

    public int getHour()
    {
        int dayMinute = Mathf.RoundToInt(24 * 60 * getDayTimeParameter());
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(dayMinute / 60f);
    }

    public int getMinute()
    {
        int dayMinute = Mathf.RoundToInt(24 * 60 * getDayTimeParameter());
        int hour = getHour();
        return Mathf.FloorToInt((dayMinute / 60f - hour) * 60f);
    }

    public int getSecond()
    {
        // What to do in here?
    }

    public string getFullTimeString()
    {
        int hour = getHour();
        int minute = getMinute();
        int second = getSecond();

        string minutesString;

        if (minute < 10)
        {
            minutesString = "0" + minute;
        }
        else {
            minutesString = "" + minute;
        }

        string hoursString;

        if (hour < 10)
        {
            hoursString = "0" + hour;
        }
        else
        {
            hoursString = "" + hour;
        }

        string secondsString;

        if (second < 10)
        {
            secondsString = "0" + second;
        }
        else
        {
            secondsString = "" + second;
        }
        return hoursString + ":" + minutesString + ":" + secondsString;
    }
```

Comment: Guys, it's not about DateTime.Now property. I have 2 time modes in my game, real & fast. Real Mode uses only DateTime.Now. I need to get Seconds as Hours and Minutes where getDayTimeParameter() is used. It returns me the part of day in 0-1 interval for Fast Mode. Minutes and Hours work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `getDayTimeParameter` function returns 0-1, and a full day equals 1

then the following should give you accurate Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

```
    public int getHour()
    {
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(getDayTimeParameter() * 24);
    }

    public int getMinute()
    {
        var hourSubtraction = getHour() * 60;
        return Mathf.FloorToInt((getDayTimeParameter() * 1440) - hourSubtraction);
    }

    public int getSecond()
    {
        var hourSubtraction = getHour() * 3600;
        var minuteSubtraction = getMinute() * 60;
        return Mathf.FloorToInt((getDayTimeParameter() * 86400) - hourSubtraction - minuteSubtraction);
    }
```

Comment: It's not about DayTime.Now property. I need to get Seconds as Hours and Minutes where getDayTimeParameter() is used. It returns me the part of day in 0-1 interval.

Comment: @DavidGhukasyan Updated my answer.

Comment: You're the best guy I have ever seen!

Comment: Ever seen? Are you stalking me? :) You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss") with its various options if necessary

Comment: It's not about DayTime.Now property. I need to get Seconds as Hours and Minutes where getDayTimeParameter() is used. It returns me the part of day in 0-1 interval.

Comment: in the accepted answer, you only want to call getDayTimeParameter once, not three times in succession -  in fact you want to call it once overall so think about passing the datetime as a parameter to each method